# How to search array in array with dynamic variables using yq

Tags: bash, shell, yq

I am having json file as
**sample.json**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "default",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name2",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "name3",
  }
]
```

Another YAML file(target.yaml)

```
-
  name: default
  webhookurl: "http://localost:9091/te"
-
  name: default1
  webhookurl: "http://localost:9091/tee"
```

I wanted to get final result as data from YAML file and perform contains operation on data from **sample.json** file.
I tried with following way
`yq e '. | .[].name | contains("default","default1")'` **sample.json**
This is giving result as follow:-
Note: sample.json is nothing but in image refers to myref.txt
[image]

Another approach tries is
`myarr=$(yq e '. | .[].name ' target.yaml)` # Put array into **myarr** variable
`yq e '. | .[].name | contains(myarr)' sample.json` # This wont work
`yq e '. | .[].name | contains(env(myarr))' sample.json`  # This wont work either

**Expected results should be**

```
default -> True
default1 -> false
```

Comment: What is your expected output here? (post the whole JSON/YAML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the two files and using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) this would work:

```bash
yq -y '(input | map(.name)) as $names | map(.name as $name | {($name): any($names[]; . == $name)})' target.yaml sample.json
```

```yaml
- default: true
- default1: false
```